# Parse REST API Java change response limit

Tags: java, rest, parse-platform, libgdx

I'm trying to change the query limit using Parse.com's REST API in Java, using libGDX.

This is the code I have attempted but it still returns the standard 100. I don't know the exact required syntax.

Here is a guide provided by Parse although it is in cURL and Python

[Here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#queries)

```
public void getPoll(){
    HttpRequest httpGet = new HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET);
    String params = "{\"limit\":1000}";
    httpGet.setUrl("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Poll/");
    httpGet.setContent(params);
    httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpGet.setHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", app_id);
    httpGet.setHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", app_key);
    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpGet,PredictionScreen.this);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `params="limit=1000"` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To give this an answer: The "params" string must be "limit=1000".

PLEASE NOTE (before downvoting): Answer was given **before Question has been marked as duplicate**. And I cannot delete an accepted answer.